# Overlay SwiftUI view over a AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-animation

I have a SwiftUI view that I would like to overlay in an exported video. I'm using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool to overlay a simple CALayer and this works, however I'm having a hard time bridging the gap between a SwiftUI view and Core Animation. Any leads or tips is appreciated, thanks!

I've tried using native CALayer and it works, but need more ideas on converting the SwiftUI view to CALayer.

Comment: If you need a single snapshot of the SwiftUI view, you could use `ImageRenderer` and then add that to the composition. If you're talking about an animated `View`, you might be out of luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.